# Discord.js stream dispatcher events

Tags: javascript, events, discord.js

I was searching all over for **ALL** stream dispatcher events, on [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher) i just found this events:
*debug, error, speaking, start, volumeChange*

But for example event *finish* isn't there.

So I'm asking, is there more events, than on [discord.js.org](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/StreamDispatcher)?

*I'm posting this, because I'm looking for an event like on pause, resume*

Comment: Seeing as discord.js.org is the *official* documentation, no there isn't.

Answer (score 2):

The StreamDispatcher class extends [WritableStream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable), that contains the events you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

According to [discordjs.guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/the-basics.html#playing-audio), there is a "finish" event if you look there.

```js
dispatcher.on('finish', () => {
    console.log('audio.mp3 has finished playing!');
});
```

Comment: Ok, but is anywhere something about event like on pause, resume?

Comment: Can you try using the events?

Comment: I'm using event finish, but events pause and resume aren't.

Comment: Hmm. Intersting.